# How to unsubscribe from this Go channel before it is empty?

Tags: go, concurrency, parallel-processing, channel

I do not understand why this code is not working:

Playground REPL: https://play.golang.org/p/4PrKFnaTeKp

```
2009/11/10 23:00:01 published message to 0 subscribers
2009/11/10 23:00:01 published message to 0 subscribers
2009/11/10 23:00:02 client 1 connected
2009/11/10 23:00:02 published message to 1 subscribers
2009/11/10 23:00:02 message received: a message for 1
2009/11/10 23:00:02 receivedMsgs: 1
2009/11/10 23:00:02 message received: a message for all
2009/11/10 23:00:02 receivedMsgs: 2
2009/11/10 23:00:02 published message to 1 subscribers
2009/11/10 23:00:03 published message to 1 subscribers
2009/11/10 23:00:03 message received: a message for 1
2009/11/10 23:00:03 receivedMsgs: 3
2009/11/10 23:00:03 message received: a message for all
2009/11/10 23:00:03 receivedMsgs: 4
2009/11/10 23:00:03 published message to 1 subscribers
2009/11/10 23:00:04 published message to 1 subscribers
2009/11/10 23:00:04 message received: a message for 1
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [select (no cases)]:
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox948233627/prog.go:70 +0xfb

goroutine 6 [chan send]:
main.(*Broker).Publish(0xc000010240, 0x4c9815, 0x11, 0x0, 0x0)
    /tmp/sandbox948233627/prog.go:121 +0x2af
main.main.func1(0xc000010240)
    /tmp/sandbox948233627/prog.go:34 +0x91
created by main.main
    /tmp/sandbox948233627/prog.go:30 +0xc7

goroutine 7 [semacquire]:
sync.runtime_SemacquireMutex(0xc000018054, 0x0, 0x1)
    /usr/local/go-faketime/src/runtime/sema.go:71 +0x47
sync.(*Mutex).lockSlow(0xc000018050)
    /usr/local/go-faketime/src/sync/mutex.go:138 +0x105
sync.(*Mutex).Lock(...)
    /usr/local/go-faketime/src/sync/mutex.go:81
main.(*Broker).Unsubscribe(0xc000010240, 0xc000062060)
    /tmp/sandbox948233627/prog.go:93 +0x1c5
main.main.func2(0xc000010240)
    /tmp/sandbox948233627/prog.go:61 +0x1a5
created by main.main
    /tmp/sandbox948233627/prog.go:40 +0xf6
```

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type Event struct {
    Message  string
    Consumer string
}

func NewEvent(msg string, consumer string) Event {
    return Event{
        Message:  msg,
        Consumer: consumer,
    }
}

type Broker struct {
    consumers map[chan Event]string
    mtx       *sync.Mutex
}

func main() {
    broker := NewBroker()

    go func() {
        for {
            time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
            broker.Publish(NewEvent("a message for 1", "1"))
            broker.Publish(NewEvent("a message for all", ""))
        }
    }()

    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)

    go func() {
        ch := broker.Subscribe("1")

        receivedMsgs := 0
        for {
            msg := <-ch
            //---> Here I'm sending message to client's browser
            //if _, err := w.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("data: %s\n\n", msg))); err != nil {
            //  log.Println(err)
            //  return
            //}
            //---> Here I unsubscribe if error in w.Flush() AKA browser was closed
            //if err := w.Flush(); err != nil {
            //log.Println("browser closed")
            //broker.Unsubscribe(ch)
            //return
            //}

            log.Println("message received:", msg.Message)

            if receivedMsgs > 3 {
                broker.Unsubscribe(ch)
                break
            }

            receivedMsgs++
            log.Println("receivedMsgs:", receivedMsgs)
        }
    }()

    select {}
}

func NewBroker() *Broker {
    return &Broker{
        consumers: make(map[chan Event]string),
        mtx:       new(sync.Mutex),
    }
}

func (b *Broker) Subscribe(id string) chan Event {
    b.mtx.Lock()
    defer b.mtx.Unlock()

    c := make(chan Event)
    b.consumers[c] = id

    log.Println(fmt.Sprintf("client %s connected", id))

    return c
}

func (b *Broker) Unsubscribe(c chan Event) {
    b.mtx.Lock()
    defer b.mtx.Unlock()

    id := b.consumers[c]
    close(c)
    delete(b.consumers, c)

    log.Printf("client %s killed, %d remaining\n", id, len(b.consumers))
}

func (b *Broker) Publish(e Event) {
    b.mtx.Lock()
    defer b.mtx.Unlock()

    pubMsg := 0

    for s, id := range b.consumers {
        if e.Consumer != "" {
            // Push to specific consumer
            if id == e.Consumer {
                s <- e
                pubMsg++

                break
            }
        } else {
            // Push to every consumer
            e.Consumer = id
            s <- e
            // Reset unused consumer
            e.Consumer = ""
            pubMsg++
        }
    }

    log.Printf("published message to %d subscribers\n", pubMsg)
}
```

When you launch:

1. it waits 2 second
2. subscribe to broker and
3. start getting messages
4. after the third message I wanna break the infinite `for` and hence the `go func` but I get an error:

If I change the line from this:

```golang
if receivedMsgs > 2 {
```

to

```golang
if receivedMsgs > 3 {
```

it works.

I think the problem is because when I call `break` there is still a message in channel `ch`.

Am I right?

How to fix this?

*I was inspired by https://gist.github.com/maestre3d/4a42e8fa552694f7c97c4811ce913e23.*

Comment: You have not really described what "works" and "doesn't work" is for your example. The error you show is the result of the behavior you say you want, and you see to confirm that with the playground example, but then directly contradict that by the description of the change you made. If you actually want to exit after the 3rd message, increment your counter before checking it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the empty select. According to this website[enter link description here](https://golangdocs.com/select-statement-in-golang) when an empty select is used the select statement blocks forever since no goroutine is available to provide any data.

To solve this I added a context with cancel which will allow me to when I unsubscribe i will stop the bottom select and stop the first goroutine https://play.golang.org/p/tZklz7iiwGd also, i remove the unnecessary mutex as you are using channels and this should be thread safe. And I also put the msgs to execute one by one as if i put both to be sent on the same goroutine this will cause a concurrency where i can send a msg to a closed channel.